# CharSequence interface in Java 11 added method `compare`. Why not `compareTo` of Comparable interface?

Tags: java, compare, string-comparison, comparable, charsequence

The [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface gained a new static method in Java 11: [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#compare(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)).

This method returns an `int`:

> the value 0 if the two CharSequence are equal; a negative integer if the first CharSequence is lexicographically less than the second; or a positive integer if the first CharSequence is lexicographically greater than the second.

That sounds just like [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). Yet the Java team obviously chose to *not* make `CharSequence` extend `Comparable`. Why not? The logic escapes me.

➥ What is it about `CharSequence::compare` that would not be an appropriate fit for `Comparable::compareTo`?

Comment: Would it present awkwardness for implementations of `CharSequence` that already provide their own `compareTo` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `Comparable<CharSequence>` wouldn't really work since [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) implements [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and [`Comparable<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

For discussion, see [this post](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8137326?focusedCommentId=13889936&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13889936) by one of the OpenJDK developers regarding the subject.

Tip from that post: A method reference of the form [`CharSequence::compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#compare(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) would be suitable as a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).